# SSIS packages with scripts cannot be upgraded to VSTA - how to fix or work around?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, visual-studio-2013, upgrade, sql-server-data-tools

I have several SSIS packages that were created and can be opened using Visual Studio 2010 with Integration Services.  I have read in many locations that newer versions of Visual Studio can open these files. I have Visual Studio 2013, so I installed [SQL Server Data Tools-Business Intelligence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966.aspx), and tried to open the solution with the SSIS project, which worked--but then, it tried to upgrade the packages, and gives me this error:

> Failed to migrate scripts contained in the package to the VSTA 11.0
>   format. Move the scripts to a new Script Component.

1. Is there any way to edit the package "the old way" in VS2013, without upgrading/migrating the package?
2. How do I obey and do what it asks me to do?  I can't find instructions anywhere. [MSDN is unhelpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522527%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
3. Can I install SQL Server Data Tools-Business Intelligence for new instances of Visual Studio 2010, so that others can edit these packages without upgrading them?  It seems like the installers are gone.

Comment: VS 2010 ties to SQL Server 2012's SSIS model. VS 2013 ties to SQL Server 2014's SSIS model. VS 2012 can go either 2012 or 2014, depending on what SSDT-BI you installed (because this isn't confusing enough). Are you changing from SQL Server 2012 to 2014? If you aren't, then you're stuck having a VS 2010/2012 shell sitting around for editing your SSIS. Help, About Microsoft Visual Studio, SQL Server Integration Services - report back the numbers from the 2010 and the 2013 versions please

Comment: Which SSDT-BI version do I need to work with SQL Server 2012 SP1 (11.0.3000)?  The links I find do not specify which SQL server they can go against.  E.g. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, none that I know of
2. Once the automatic upgrade has finished. You open each package with scripts. Open each script task/transformation. Recompile. Save. And Close.
3. Not that I know of.

This has worked for me upgrading from 2008 to 2012 and I think also applies to 2010 to 2012/3

Note that I think once you've upgraded the package - VS2010 should still be able to work with the package, but if you install the SSDT-BI for VS2013 then this will install the VS2013 Shell (enough to edit the packages) even if you don't have the the full VS2013 available.

Edit:

Do you have SQL Server 2012 SP2? I've found an issue with SSIS packages using VSTA on SP2 in that they won't open (ie. the designer won't open) and also they fail at run time. At this stage I've gone back from SP2 to continue working.

Comment: I do have VS2013 installed as well, so I will try SSDT-BI for VS2013 soon.

Comment: I am working with SQL Server 2012 SP1.  Do you have more info on this problem with SP2? Should I lobby my DBAs not to upgrade to SP2?

Comment: Will upgrading the packages to SSDT-BI-VS2013 even work with SQL Server 2014?  I decided to stick with VS2012 and SSDT-BI I found for it here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=393520 ; that seems to work much better.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask: Will upgrading the packages to SSDT-BI-VS2013 even work with SQL Server 2012?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - I'm not sure mate. I've not to 2013 yet. I'm still on VS2012 but all logic dictates that this would have been a minor upgrade.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, I can tell you for certain that packages upgraded to SSDT-BI-VS2013 will _**not**_ run on SSIS 2012. The format of the .dtsx file changes in a way that SSIS 2012 cannot comprehend.